# Using C++ API in the browser from an emscripten-generated JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

Let's say I have a basic C++ API as follows:

```
#include <random>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

int getRandomInt(int low, int high) {
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist (low, high);
return dist(mt);
}

float getRandomFloat(float low, float high) {
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist (low, high);
return dist(mt);
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(hello_world_module) {
using namespace emscripten;
// function("lerp", &lerp);
function("getRandomInt", &getRandomInt);
function("getRandomFloat", &getRandomFloat);
}
```

I want to generate these functions for the browser. As it stands right now I know how to do this for a node JavaScript module using these commands:

```
em++ -std=c++11 -Wall -fPIC --minify 0 -O2 --bind --memory-init-file 0 \
-s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1 \
-s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 \
random_api.cpp -o random_api.js
```

Inside node I can run these commands (let's say `node run_random_api.js`):

```
var random_api = require('./random_api.js')

console.log("getRandomInt(0, 100)", random_api.getRandomInt(0, 100));
console.log("getRandomInt(0, 100)", random_api.getRandomInt(0, 100));
console.log("getRandomInt(0, 100)", random_api.getRandomInt(0, 100));
```

Now how could I get `run_random_api.js` working in the browser? 
I tried `browserify` on `run_random_api.js` and turning it into a `bundle.js` but that said `random_api.getRandomInt` is not a function (google-chrome 64.0.3282.167)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the script as any other JavaScript. Then you can access the exported functions via the `Module` such as `Module.getRandomInt()`.

Inside the html load the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="random_api.js"></script>
```

And then you have access to your functions like this

```
function getRandomInt(low, high) {
    console.log(Module.getRandomInt(low,high));
}
```

You can read more about the `Module` object [here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/module.html).

Comment: This is what I needed. I had tried it before too but I couldn't get it to work so I moved on. The problem was that in my `index.html`, I had put my `getRandomInt` function call in a JavaScript file whose script tag was placed/loaded above the `random_api.js` tag. Order matters I guess.